# EPPLus Error when loading a Stream larger than 40MB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I am using EPPlus on C# MVC to load excel files into memory.
I am taking the stream from a file upload:

```
model.File.InputStream
```

and pass this to the ExcelPackage.Load() Method.

It works great for files < 40 MB. But for larger files, I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in EPPlus.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the project to x64 fixed the issue!

- If you're using this on IIS you have to set the pool to run on x64.
- On IIS Express you have to [Enable x64 bit version](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/12/01/enable-x64-bit-version-of-iis-express/)